# I am quite positive that this function is non-negative -- How to calculate/proof

Tags: equation-solving

I have this function and running some experiments with the 3DPlot shows that this function "must be" non-negative (formerly I wrongfully asked for positivity) everywhere. However, the Reduce does not terminate. Is there an optimized calculation method? Or do you see the analytical reason for this positiveness?

```
  e[p_, d_, l_] = 5 (4 d + l) (-1 + p) (d + l)^(1/(-1 + p)) - ((4 d + l)/4)^(1/(-1 + p)) (20 d (-1 + p) + l (-3 + 5 p))
  Plot3D[{e[p, 0.1000, l]}, {l, 0, 100}, {p, 1.1, 10}]   

  Reduce[{e[p, d, l] < 0, p > 1, d > 0, l >= 0}, {p, d, l}]
```

Thank you very much in advance
Paul

Comment: Is this inequality too tough, or am I missing sth.? Is there a somehow numerical way to come close to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You only restrict `l` to be nonnegative but then it can be `0`.

```
e[p, d, 0] (* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thx Alan, you are right. However, I corrected my question, because I in fact need non-negativity.

Comment: OK, but it would be nice if the edit were clearly marked so this correct answer does not appear to miss the point.  If it helps, any simplification problem lies in non-integer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You can come *close* to a solution with numerical optimization:

```
e[p_, d_, l_] := 
  5 (4 d + l) (-1 + 
      p) (d + l)^(1/(-1 + p)) - ((4 d + l)/
       4)^(1/(-1 + p)) (20 d (-1 + p) + l (-3 + 5 p));

FindMinimum[{e[p, d, l], p > 1 && d > 0 && l >= 0}, {p, d, l}, 
 MaxIterations -> 150, AccuracyGoal -> 30]
```

with output

```
{-0.000488281, {p -> 108055., d -> 434427., l -> 0.}}
```

However there seems to be numerical issues within Mathematica since

```
e[108055, 434427, 0]
```

returns `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. With this result it seems that e>=0 is almost surely at least zero. But you also have no analytical idea, right?